# Reverse-engineering one-time passwords for two-factor authentication systems

Tags: java, security

Given a one-time password generator that is time-based (such as Google Authenticator), how many instances of (time, PIN) pairs would one need to significantly weaken the algorithm to a point where one would be able to narrow down possible seeds to the original function? If one were to send out PINs to clients via SMS or email (instead of using a keyfob or the actual Google Authenticator app which does not let one see past PINs), would a compromise that reveals past PINs be a significant threat to the system (note that both emails and SMS carry relatively precise time information)?

- Details of the OTP Algorithm: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt
- Reference Java Implementation:
  http://rfc-ref.org/RFC-TEXTS/4226/chapter16.html

Comment: Cannot speak to the mathematical chance that a detailed analysis of past PINs would reveal a flaw in the algorithm - I suppose that would depend very much on the algorithm itself.  But I know Facebook has a working implementation of two-factor authentication sent via SMS upon a login attempt.  Every time you log into Facebook, you receive an SMS with a one-time-password in it.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: Wonder if you'd be more likely to get answers on http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @phs The question is related to the design of a two-factor authentication system whether it should involve any timestamped storage of the one-time passwords generated. If this significantly weakens the security of the system, then one would argue that the design should not include any storage of past OTPs (emails, SMS or otherwise).

Comment: @smparkes Thanks, I'll cross-post there and add a link to this question.

Comment: Question re-asked on security.stackexchange.com, http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11133/reverse-engineering-one-time-passwords-for-two-factor-authentication-systems

Comment: For future reference (not this time since you've reposted): questions can be migrated to another site by moderators (use the `flag` button to request one).

Comment: Closed as cross-site re-post: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/11133